# Проблемы в создании RSS страницы

Tags: php, rss

Сам не умею делать rss, поэтому код нашел в инете и сделал под себя, но почему-то появляются ошибки. Проверял через валидатор rss на сайте http://validator.w3.org/feed/.
введите этот сайт draw-art.ru/rss/rss_me.php и там всплывут ошибки, если надо, ошибки могу сюда выложить.

**Добавлено.**

```
<?php
header("content-type: application/rss+xml");
include "db.php";
echo "
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"windows-1251\"?>
<rss version=\"2.0\">
<channel>
<title>сайт о рисовании</title>
<link>http://www.draw-art.ru</link>
<description>Новости о поступлении новых уроков по рисованию,фотошоп,matte-painting,и новости моего блога</description>
<language>ru</language>";

$result = dbquery("SELECT date FROM blog ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,1");
$data   = dbarray($result);
$lnd    = $data['date'];
$upldt  = date("r", $lnd); // конвертация даты в формат RFC 2822
echo "<lastBuildDate>$upldt</lastBuildDate>
";

$result = dbquery("SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10");
while ($data = dbarray($result)) {
    echo "<item>
";
    echo "<title>" . $data['title'] . "</title>
";
    echo "<link>http://www.draw-art.ru/blog_look.php?id=" . $data['id'] . "</link>
";
    echo "<description>" . $data['description'] . "</description>
";

    $nd   = $data['date'];
    $updt = date("r", $nd);
    echo "<pubDate>$updt</pubDate>
";
    echo "<guid>http://www.draw-art.ru/blog_look.php?id=" . $data['id'] . "</guid>
";
    echo "</item>
";
}

echo "</channel>
</rss>";
?>
```

Comment: Выложите rss_me.php сюда, тут как бы экстрасенсов нету, насколько я знаю.

Comment: ошибка где то в скрипте, он даже не запускается (может быть где то пропустили кавычку)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/p45291/www/draw-art.ru/rss/rss_me.php on line 4*

В самом начале замените свою часть кода на ту что привожу ниже.

```
echo '
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"windows-1251\"?>
<rss version=\"2.0\">
<channel>
<title>сайт о рисовании</title>
<link>http://www.draw-art.ru</link>
<description>Новости о поступлении новых уроков по рисованию,фотошоп,matte-painting,и новости моего блога</description>
<language>ru</language>';
```

Comment: помогло ,только потом вылезли другие ошибки (: кароче дырявый скрипт скачал легче наверно новый найти , неподскажите где есть нормальный написаный на php.

Comment: там такая ошибка вышла 


This feed does not validate.

'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 90-93: invalid data (maybe a high-bit character?) [help]


line 3, column 0: XML parsing error: <unknown>:3:0: XML or text declaration not at start of entity [help]

Comment: замените windows-1251 на utf-8